# Why isn't this statement about direct sums of injective modules contradicting the proposition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

I am trying to read Tsit-Yuen Lam's *"Lectures on Modules and Rings"* in order to understand why any abelian group can be injected in an injective abelian group, but I got confused by the following proposition [on page 61](https://books.google.ie/books?id=r9VoYbk-8c4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> [image]

After proving this result, he states that a direct sum of injective modules doesn't have to result in an injective module, and that it is only guaranteed in a finite direct sum. Why doesn't this contradict the proposition?

Comment: Well, direct sums and direct products only coincide for finitely many factors.

Comment: Wow... Well, thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I guess I'm still not fluent with direct sums and products.